# Internet connectivity stops on iPhone but no issues on Windows 10 Laptop?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, iphone

For the past 10 days, I've submitted complains to my ISP regarding loss of internet connectivity at frequent intervals. However, the ISP reported everything to be working fine from their end. This led me to run a few diagnostics using my laptop. I ran a continuous ping test and didn't find a single connection drop. However, all our iPhones connected to the same wireless router frequently lose internet connectivity at different time instances, although connection to the wireless router remains stable.

At this moment, I cannot use any apps on the iPhone or browse anything while browsing works completely fine on the Windows 10 laptop. The loss of connectivity happens for about 10 seconds after which it starts working again.

**Update:**

1. iPhones lose connection at different times, not simultaneously.
2. The router page also fails to open during the time there is no
   connection.

Comment: So it’s just the iPhones which exhibit connectivity losses? Are the devices updated to the latest iOS? What model are they? iPhone 5? 6+?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 Yes just the iPhones. They are running the latest iOS. An iPhone 6 and another iPhone 7 Plus.

Comment: Can you access your router’s settings page from your iPhones? Do the iPhones report ‘No Internet Connection’?

Comment: I haven’t tried opening the router page, however the iPhones do not report anything. The Safari browser just keeps loading, so do the items on Instagram or Snapchat. They keep loading forever.

Comment: Silly question. Is the laptop connected wirelessly?

Comment: @Appleoddity Yes they are connected exactly to the same wireless router. That is what makes me wonder.

Comment: The router page also fails to open during the no connectivity duration. Secondly, the iPhones lose connection at different times, not simultaneously.

Comment: How far from the router are you when you lose connection?   For example my laptop works wirelessly in my garage but my iPhones do not.  They show connected but just spin. Do you experience e internet loss if the phones are in the same room as the router?   This may just be interference.

Comment: Is your router dual-band? (2.4ghz and 5ghz) or just single-band? (2.4ghz or 5ghz)

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 WR-941nd

Comment: It's a 2.4ghz router. Have you considered connecting the laptop to the router via ethernet and then using the iPhones?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 Yes I have. What does that do though since the laptop works fine even on wireless. Also loss of connection even happens when the laptop is powered off.

Comment: Answer to your first question: Reduce interference on the already congested 2.4ghz network. Your remark about the loss of connection still happening: Have you tried to use another router like the one provided to you by your ISP?

Comment: Oh got it now. I have a Range Extender  WR840N connected to the Wireless of the original Huawei router provided by ISP. Same issue happens on that. How do I be sure if its congestion?

Comment: Btw I use only 5 or 6 devices on both my routers at maximum. Both have a separate Channel either 1,6 or 11 and I hardly get any neighbors signal within my home so not sure what could cause congestion.